# Javascript + Multipart/Form Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipartform-data

I have a service which allows to fill information about some object. One of the attributes is picture. Before now I used to upload picture through file open dialog from desktop. Now want to make it possible to load picture by URL, but I have no idea how to load it by URL and make it a form-data parameter (so that both ways were possible). I'm constructing form-data like this

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("img", imgFile);
fd.append("data", "somedata")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this implementation. [Uploading files and JSON data in the same request with Angular JS](http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/)

Comment: I have no problem with downloading JSON and files together. I have problem with supporting both variants of upload: through openFileDialog and through URL

Comment: When you are entering URL, try downloading it and append it  file(images) array. then you can use same implementation that you have for File Dialog. Hope this works.